# Edit Firefox multi container configuration

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, internet-security, private-browsing, firefox-quantum

I have several containers configured on my Firefox and I have been using for a while, so container have information associated.

However,  sometimes I was not very focused and I used the wrong one for specific task, so I don't know what webpage cookies are associated to each container.

In other words I would like to know where containers store their information, and how to edit this information in the most friendly way.

Comment: I think this question could only be answered by a Mozilla dev who has worked with the contextual identities project. You might want to reach out to them in another forum.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the key thing.

There is a  column "originAttributes" in cookies.sqlite database.
In this column sometimes there is a string like ^userContextId=6 and in these strings ^userContextId=x the x value identifies a container.